# Multiple Capybara exceptions in Ruby

Tags: ruby, error-handling, capybara

I have the following two rescue statements. My test data contains scenarios that should create exception report entries and do rescue actions for each type of exception.

Both of the exceptions are logged and the program rescues for both, however, only the first error type is recorded.

```
    rescue Capybara::ElementNotFound
      $logfile.puts "#{$date_now}: Missing details for Row #{$row+1}"
      puts "Foo Error for Row #{$row+1}\n"
      return
   rescue Capybara::Ambiguous
     $logfile.puts "#{$date_now}: Duplicated details for Row #{$row+1}"
     puts "Bar Error for Row #{$row+1}\n"
     return
   else
   @court = first('li.offence-court > p')
   end
```

I'm getting:

```
Foo Error for Row 3
Foo Error for Row 4
```

And if the order of the rescue statements is swapped around, I get Bar error messages. How can I get the correct error message shown for each type of exception?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Capybara::Ambiguous is derived from Capybara::ElementNotFound](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara.rb#L12), so Capybara::Ambiguous needs to come first.

```
rescue Capybara::Ambiguous
  ...
rescue Capybara::ElementNotFound
  ...
```

If in that order it prints out the same thing for both errors, then both are actually the same type of error

Comment: Tom, would the handling of the exceptions vary depending on the type of loop you were using?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't think so.